# MFC: Representing adjacency matrix in edit box

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog based programm (MFC), where I want to make an adjacency graph representation. I have an edit box (IDC_EDIT) and MFC Masked Edit control (IDC_VERTEXES), which has a mask with 2 digits.

I wrote a code, where upon losing focus on IDC_VERTEXES, the IDC_EDIT will be filled with matrix, where all numbers will be 0.

```
void CTAB1::OnEnKillfocusVertexes()
{
    CString Text;
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_VERTEXES, Text);
    int x = _wtoi(Text);
    if (!Text.IsEmpty()) {
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT, L"");
    }
    CEdit* pEdit = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT);
    int nPos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {   

            pEdit->SetSel(nPos, nPos);
            pEdit->ReplaceSel(L"0");
            pEdit->ReplaceSel(L" ");

        }
        pEdit->ReplaceSel(L"\r\n");
    }

}
```

It works as I wanted, except one thing. Let's say if IDC_VERTEXES is 3 (x = 3). The IDC_EDIT should be like this:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

But it looks like this:

```
0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0
```

Did I miss something or I put \r\n in a wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting the caret position to the start of edit control, in every iteration.

Instead you can set the caret position once at the start. `ReplaceSel` will simply insert at the caret and moves the caret forward. Example:

```
pEdit->SetSel(nPos, nPos);
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < x; j++)
    {
        pEdit->ReplaceSel(L"0");
        pEdit->ReplaceSel(L" ");
    }
    pEdit->ReplaceSel(L"\r\n");
}
```

Or you can put `pEdit->SetSel(nPos, nPos);` at the start of each row (this will insert rows in reverse order)